# Cannot Upload multiple Files in IE 11 (through popup / iFrame)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iframe

it's seems not a SharePoint problem and may be browser behavior, may I ask your help?

Current Situation:

I tried to add the ASP.NET file upload control to allow users upload file from my SharePoint Web Part to SharePoint 2013 Document Library.

In IE 10, I can  select multiple files for uploading but I can select only single file in IE 11 
if I used HTML iFrame to connect the SharePoint  and the iFrame added in the popup page .

Code -  ASP.NET File Upload Control:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fuFilePath" runat="server" Width="500px" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

Code -  iFrame in popup (redirect SharePoint Web Part URL in run-time):

```
 <iframe id="IfSharePoint" width="100%" height="650px" runat="server"></iframe>
```

Please advise if any work around or idea for this issues, thank you very much.